# Inserting HTML data into db table

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I'm using following function before insertion html markup data into db table

```
function html($data, $db)
{     
    $data = $db->escape_string($data);
    return $data;
}
```

But there is problem: i see "/" - slash before every " symbol
For ex.

```
<p style=\"margin-top: 15px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 0px; \">
```

How to deal with that problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it depends on what your escape_string() function does.
And, moreover, wheter you have [**magic_quotes_gpc**](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) directive turned on or off (it should be off by default).

In order to insert safely into a database, you need to use [**mysql_real_escape_string()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)
. **NO addslashes()**, **NO home-brewed functions**, but that one. Or, even better, use parametrized queries which lifts off your work of escaping quotes. Try with [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

**EDIT :**

**saw now the mysqli tag, so mysql_real_escape_string() is not an option, but the magic_quotes directive could still be the culprit for this.**

In case you have magic_quotes on you can either turn them off in your PHP ini, through `ini_set('magic_quotes_gpc',0);` , *.htacces* `php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off` or have a simple function like this:

```
function escape($value)
{
  if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
  {
    $value = stripslashes($value);
  }
  //return mysql_real_escape_string($value);  changed after update
  return $value;
}
```

<strike>Be sure to have an open connection before using mysql_real_escape_string() or it will return FALSE.</strike>

Also, html DOESN'T NEED TO BE ESCAPED before going into a database. I mean, you need to escape YOUR QUERIES, and you achieve that by the methods I mentioned. Html and its maliciousness DOES NOTHING to the database.

Html needs to be escape ON OUTPUT, and only then, and you use [**htmlentities()**](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) at minimum, but further action is required in order to escape any possibile XSS injection vulnerabilities. It's a complex subject, it requires a lot of work in order to escape invisible control characters, malicious tags, and so on. You need to make further reasearch into this , and start reading about XSS Injection threats.

Anyway, not allowing a code to be executed on the browser is a start for this. **Don't allow users to write html directly on your page** (the same advice applies not only on user-submitted inputs, but on everything that comes from outside, like a $_GET parameter, or a Cookie, or even hidden form values) or you'll easily have a `<script></script>` dangerous problem, that can lead to cookie stealing, bad redirecting, traffic hijacking, an so many things I can't list here. USually htmlentities() provides a good level of protection against that, even though its output mithgt not be pretty.

Comment: Getting error `Call to undefined function magic_quotes_gpc() `

Comment: and what function to use before output

Comment: @user978733 the function is `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php

Comment: htmlentities() can do the trick. See my answer, I added a bit more information

Answer (score 4):

`mysql_real_escape_string` is the answer

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: listen i'm using mydqli, escape and real_escape are the same things in mysqli syntax, read the documentation before answering

Comment: well, you never mentioned it.

Comment: @user978733, you are correct if a bit rude. Janis, mysql_* and mysqli_* functions do not mix!. Furthermore `mysql_escape_string` is depreciated in mysql_*, but in mysqli `mysqli_escape_string` is the same as `mysqli_real_escape_string`, is the same as `db->escape_string`, very annoying these inconsistencies.

Comment: @user978733 don't be rude. People are answering here because they want to help you. You should be thankful for that. And the $db-> doesn't necessary means that you are using mysqli.

Comment: I would recommend always using db->real_escape_string, that is always the correct function, no matter the lib you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Your are getting with "/" because server is enabled the magic_quotes_gpc. 
you have to check the magic_quotes_gpc is enable or not.

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $text = stripslashes($text);
}
else {
    $text = $text;
}
```

use get_magic_quotes_gpc() to check.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php to store html in the database.

Comment: -1 That is great when using PDO, but will get you SQL-injection pwnd when not using PDO.

Comment: @Johan The problem at hand here was inserting html in the database and not inputed html.

Comment: you can **never** trust any data from outside the db, always escape it, even if you wrote it yourself. The best way is of course to use PDO, then you can just insert it as is.